# Is declaring a variable with auto and initializing with a primitive literal defined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I initialise a variable declared using auto with a primitive literal, are the results defined e.g.

```
auto i = 6; // Is this always going to evaluate to a int?
            // Or could it evaluate to some similar type like short?
```

Comment: It is well defined. Btw; you could just look it up in the standard ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of integer literal `6` is *int*, as you can check [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Then, from the [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

> For variables, *auto* specifies that the type of the variable that is being 
>   declared will be automatically deduced from its initializer.

So `i` will have type of *int*, because `6` has type of *int*.

And this behaviour is absolutely well-defined.

Comment: I think you mean [cppreference.com](http://www.cppreference.com), cpp.reference.com doesn't exist.

Comment: @Bim yeah, definitely! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's exactly what `auto` is for.

For example, `auto i;` wouldn't make sense. The compiler uses `6` to deduce the type. And `6` is an integer literal.

Comment: Sorry, I guess the question wasn't clear, is it guaranteed to evaluate to an int? Or could using some compilers, it evaluate to a short or long?

Comment: @George Yes, guaranteed to an `int` because `6` is an integer literal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because every literal has a well defined type. The type of literal `6` is `int`. So, your `auto` will be translated to `int`.

If `int` is 16 or 32 bits long is implementation defined, but that's doesn't produce undefined behaviour, because every simple `int` through your program has a same length. Besides that, irrespective of the length of a `int` according to your architecture, 6 is an `int`, not `short` or `long`.